# Window-borders disappears in Unity

Tags: unity, window-decoration

Recently I found that window borders keep disappearing intermittently in Unity! Especially when either Google Chrome or Mozilla Thunderbird are running.

Is there a way out?

Comment: I have the same issue and a two more: My indicator applets cease to be clickable at random time intervals and sometimes the part, where the unity launcher is hidden is cut off.

Answer (score 10):

Usually restarting unity helps. You can do this by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing:

```
unity --replace
```

Note: Don't execute this command in a terminal otherwise unity will be killed, when the terminal is closed.

This is of course not a fix. Just a way to undo the error once it has occurred. I suppose these bugs (and the ones posted in my comments to your question) will be fixed with future updates. There are many bug-reports on launchpad concerning these.

You could also try ans install [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager] / `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` and play with the setting there. It might or might not help - depending on who you ask.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the prompt reply, it solved my problem, though I wish there was a more permanent solution for this bugging issue.

Comment: As I said, there will be in the future versions. Unity isn't mature yet. If you liked the answer: How about an upvote and/or marking it accepted?

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled keeping minimized windows thumbnails under "workarounds" in ccsm?  If so, disable it -- it messed up my unity bad.

Comment: I checked the settings in ccsm. "keeping minimized windows thumbnails" is not enabled. So I guess I'll have to do with "unity --replace" till the bug gets fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue **permanently** by entering CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM) —if you don't have it do `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`—, going into the *Window Decorations* options, and changing the *Command* setting to `compiz-decorator`.

Backing out of this menu, then unchecking Window Decoration, allowing the desktop to reload, then checking Window Decoration and exiting out of CCSM.

After doing this, I can no longer reproduce the issue.